# VB6 Listview MultiSelect Property Code

Tags: listview, properties, vb6

At first, I created a listview that is  on fullrow select. But it only selects one item from the listview. here is my code. This how it works, user clicks item in the listview, and then it will deduct the quantity from the inventory.
It very tiresome to one-by-one click all items if I have many items to click.

```
y = ListView3.SelectedItem.SubItems(4)
ConnectDB
    rs.Open "Select * from inventory where ProductNumber = " & y, db, 3, 3
    rs(5) = txtStockLeft
        rs.Update
    Set rs = Nothing
    db.Close:  Set db = Nothing
ListView3.ListItems.Remove ListView3.SelectedItem.Index
```

So I found out that, listview has multiselect property. You can select multiple items and then press the command. And i have no idea about how to code it. Any help will be appreciated.

```
EDITed for Alex K.
```

Here is my code. I put the updating field, but error on txtStockLeft

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
ConnectDB
Dim li As ListItem
For Each li In ListView3.ListItems

If li.Selected Then '// is selected item
    txtStockLeft = ListView3.SelectedItem.SubItems(3)
    db.Execute "rs(5) = " & txtStockLeft & " where ProductNumber = " & li.SelectedItem.SubItems(4), , adCmdText
End If
Next

db.Close: Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

Method or data member not found is the error, and highlights the error to txtStockleft

Comment: Are you saying you want to get all the selected items from the listbox?

Comment: from my listview, yes. With their corresponding stocks, it will deduct  the purchased item from the stock.

Answer (score 0):

In code or the properties window you need `ListView3.MultiSelect = True`

You simply ctrl/shift/click and select, then in a button event (a listview click would obliviously cause problems):

```
ConnectDB

Dim li As ListItem
For Each li In ListView3.ListItems

    If li.Selected Then '// is selected item
        db.execute "update inventory set ????? = " & txtStockLeft & " where ProductNumber = " & li.SelectedItem.SubItems(4), , adCmdText
    End If

Next

db.Close: Set db = Nothing
```

This SQL method avoids the potentially expensive full table read you currently have, just replace `?????` with the update field name.

(Also make sure `txtStockLeft` is validated)

Comment: i got an error, "method or data member not found " and highlights to txtStockLeft. And then i put this 
txtStockLeft = ListView3.SelectedItem.SubItems(3)
   same error occurs. I dont have idea. i will edit my question so you can see the code